# Pull down to discard - android

Tags: android, listview, animation

I have a listview that slides up, triggered by an onclick event of a view. Now I want the user to be able to drag or pull down this listview to discard it. What I'm looking for is implemented in the google play music app where you can simply swipe down on the currently playing music and bring it to the bottom bar. 
However, I don't have a bottom bar as I want to discard the view completely.
How do I implement this?

Comment: usually drag down on a listview is understood as scroll up or refresh.